# Grammatical/lexical words and levels of formality

Tags: verbs, english-comparison, nouns, adverbs, vocabulary

In English, there are a bunch of grammatical or lexical concept that can be expressed in at least two ways depending on the level of formality, e.g.:

```
although/though 
do not/don't
dad/father
```

I am looking for similar word pairs for Italian. This is an example:

```
ma,però/tuttavia
retrocedere/andare indietro
restituire/dare indietro
```

Comment: Even though this is an interesting topic, I doubt it is right for italian.SE: it doesn't admit a precise answer, but rather a list of examples. Other opinions?

Comment: Even in reference to those words you have proposed for such a comparison, it is difficult to say which is more or less formal. However "ma, però" is not an expression I use frequently. If you need some suggestion, it would be better you refer to a more contextualized example.

Comment: @DaG It's too broad, I believe. Every language has different linguistic registers; moreover the lexical choices can depend on the speaker's culture and background.

Comment: @egreg: Way too broad, indeed. Almost any concept in almost any language has several ways to express it in different registers, from the most colloquial/slang/jocular to the most formal/elegant. *Uomo*, *tizio*, *signore*, *individuo*... *Casa*, *domicilio*, *dimora*... *Cibo*, *roba da mangiare*, *alimenti*... etc. Don't get me started on body parts, sexual practices and the like. And I'm not even taking into account the possibilities allowed by *vezzeggiativi*, *peggiorativi* and so on.

Comment: @Kyriakos Kyritsis: http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/incontro-congiunzioni-per

Comment: the real trouble is that different linguistic registers in Italian are used in a funny way. In an legal text, for example, you will find *velocipedi* and not *biciclette* ...

Comment: @mau You also find *obliterare* instead of *timbrare* on ticket machines on buses. The worst is using *ovvero* meaning *oppure* (I find it alike to *piuttosto che* in adversative sense).

Comment: @egreg I see "ovvero" more like "in other words", but also like "or rather...".

Comment: @Alenanno Bureaucrats use it only in the second sense, in common spoken language it's most probably in the first sense.